# RxJava: Reading multiple subscriptions and performing an action based on their results?

Tags: java, android, rx-java

I have a network call that depends on the inputs of multiple UI elements. It's basically an interface for a transaction, where the user can pick things like the amount, currency, and destination. Before the request is fired off, I need to verify everything (for example, whether or not the user's balance has the amount, whether or not the destination is valid, etc.). I have `Observable`s for all of these network calls, but I'm not sure what the best way to go about starting all of these calls concurrently and using their results to determine what action to take.

Basically, the ideal flow is for each condition to have a failure case (which I can determine in code for each), and if any of those failure cases are met, display an error to the user saying which inputs were invalid. If all of the checks pass, fire off the transaction.

How should I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, the signatures of your Observables look similar to this:

```
// verifier Observables which perform network calls
Observable<Verification1> test1 = ...
Observable<Verification2> test2 = ...
...

// Observable to fire the transaction
Observable<TransactionResult> fireTransaction = ... 

// represents the clicks on the "go" button of the UI
Observable<Void> goButtonClicks = ...
```

Then you could combine all these Observables as follows:

```
goButtonClicks.flatMap(theVoid -> {
   return Observable.zip(
      test1.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()),
      test2.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()),
      (v1, v2) -> {
         if (v1 and v2 pass all your requirements) {
            return fireTransaction;
         } else {
            return Observable.just(new TransactionFailure("error"));
         }
      }
   );
}).subscribe(transactionResult -> {
   UI.showMessage(transactionResult.getMessage());
})
```

The `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())` calls give you parallelism in the verification network calls, and `zip` allows you to "wait" on all results.

*However*, I guess that on the server side, you will have to do all these tests again for security reasons. So if you can change the architecture, you may want to always "fire" the transaction in the UI, let the server make the checks, and return a success/failure notification to the UI.

Comment: Thanks so much, I'll try this out! I can't change the server behavior, as it's a third-party API.